# Javascript Firefox restart

Tags: javascript, firefox

I upgraded from Firefox 38 to 46 and this script is not working properly, by that it is meant that it is supposed to shut down and restart Firefox but after the upgrade it only shuts down.

```
const nsIAppStartup = Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup;

// Notify all windows that an application quit has been requested.
var os = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
var cancelQuit = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-PRBool;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsPRBool);
os.notifyObservers(cancelQuit, "quit-application-requested", null);

// Something aborted the quit process. 
if (cancelQuit.data)
    return;

// Notify all windows that an application quit has been granted.
os.notifyObservers(null, "quit-application-granted", null);

// Enumerate all windows and call shutdown handlers
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var windows = wm.getEnumerator(null);
while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
    var win = windows.getNext();
    if (("tryToClose" in win) && !win.tryToClose())
        return;
}
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1"].getService(nsIAppStartup)
    .quit(nsIAppStartup.eRestart | nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit);
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug introduced in Firefox 45 that broke some uses of
`quit-application-granted`, responsible for notifying observers (e.g. addons or
scripts) that the browser is going to shut down.

It should be fixed in 48 and up. For more information, please see:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269859
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1284687

Changeset with the fix:

> We were closing the windows before to improve perceived shutdown
>   performance, but we end up in a state where we're likely to miss
>   out on the last ~2 seconds of session activity for most tabs per
>   window. This is because we were removing the session update
>   message listeners and resolving the flush Promises once the
>   domwindowclosed notification fired for the window.
>
> Hiding the window allows us to wait for the messages properly.
>
> What's more, we weren't even collecting the window state after
>   we had flushed, so we have *always* been missing (in the worst
>   case) about 2 seconds of session state per window. This addresses
>   that.
>
> – [Bug 1284687 - Hide windows on shutdown while persisting session instead of closing them](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/51efc2643b80)